# Decode parameters on contract creation or constructor parameters

Tags: solidity, abi, constructor

I want to decode parameters passed to contract constructor. Even if i used the ABI of the contract, it doesn't seem to resolve the parameters used.

Here is the transaction trace out put
https://gist.github.com/Bereket-G/71df576e8a132d72406cb2b48e92505e

```
constructor(bytes32 _password) public {
    locked = true;
    password = _password;
  }
```

The passed parameter value (`_password`) was `0x412076657279207374726f6e67207365637265742070617373776f7264203a29`. Surprisingly i found it on the last part of the data passed for the CREATE type call.

My gut feeling is this CREATE type transaction also passes the the contract bytecode along so it might not be possible to get passed parameters with normal way of decoding transaction with ABI.